# gdal_calc returning incorrect value in decimal part

Tags: gdal-calc

I am using gdal_calc to fill some of the no-data values of one raster from another raster. Here is my command. Both have the same projection, cell size, etc. The output value in the resultant raster is different from the source raster, the difference is only in the decimal part. See the image below. I cannot understand why this is happening. The data can be found to reproduce the issue [here](https://dewberryportal-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/asiddiqui_dewberry_com/EXywa57fV4dArF9jgvWG3AYBhP6KsWB_48aZczEJCM9pOA?e=ghlyN1).

[image]

source raster: 25_1001
raster to fill: 25_1002
output: output

```sh
gdal_calc.bat --overwrite --calc "((A==-9999)*((B)+9999)) + A " --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:/Users/asiddiqui/Downloads/gdal_calc_issue/25_1002.tif --A_band 1 -B C:/Users/asiddiqui/Downloads/gdal_calc_issue/25_1001.tif --hideNoData --outfile C:/Users/asiddiqui/Downloads/gdal_calc_issue/OUTPUT.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like regular ol' floating point error.

Try `--calc "where(A == -9999, B, A)"` to choose the value of B when A is nodata, rather than using floating point arithmetic try to arrive at the same value.